# How many students chose lessons $A$ and $B$?

Tags: combinatorics

In a class in which the students must choose at least two lessons, $15$ students chose lesson $A$, $12$ students chose lesson $B$, and $17$ students chose lesson $C$. According to this, how many students are there who chose lessons $A$ and $B$?

I've tried solving it by Venn diagram. However, I couldn't work it out.

Kindest Regards

Comment: Can anyone take a look?

Comment: There is not enough information in this problem to be able to solve it. Are you sure you have not missed out any information?

Comment: @JohnDoe That was from our worksheet which is for training exams. Indeed, you are too right because they hadn't given enough information. this is not first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I don't get the exact result.

Say there is $x$ students taking all three.
$a+x$ students taking A and C, $b+x$ students taking A and B and $c+x$ students taking B and C. Then we have $$a+b+x = 15$$ $$b+c+x = 12$$ and $$a+c+x=17$$
Thus $$15+12-17 =(a+b+x)+(b+c+x)-(c+a+x) = 2b+x$$
but you are interested in $b+x$

Comment: We can't solve this question, right?

Comment: Right............

Comment: Ok, I wanna accept your answer =))